# How can i use react-dropzone-uploader for uploading image data to API and get back resulted image from that API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dropzone

I am using React-Dropzone-Uploader for uploading the images to my API.

The API takes Request Body:

```
{ 
    image: “file”
}
```

and gives
Success Response Data:

```
{ 
    success: true, message: “success” // all user, plan info data 
}
```

I am not able to do that.

I am using axios for API calls.

''let image=files API.post('/web/v1.0/upload',{image}).then(response=>{ console.log(response.data) })''

Comment: can you share your code how you have implemented without knowing the code flow how can we solve your issue

Comment: @techipank I am not able to find out where to put my API call.When i am trying to hit my API,I am getting 401 unauthorized error.

Comment: You can ask your backend for the api endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are facing this issue because your request is not authenticated 401 is nothing to do with axios check the API and if it is required authentication send your `auth_token` like this:

```
headers : {
  'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
  'Accept' : 'application/json',
  'Authorization' : 'Bearer <token_here>'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen examples provided at https://react-dropzone-uploader.js.org/docs/examples ?

Please provide exact problem you are facing with it.

Comment: I am not able to find out where to put my API call.When i am trying to hit my API,I am getting 401 unauthorized error.   ''let image=files
              API.post('/web/v1.0/upload',{image}).then(response=>{
                  console.log(response.data)
              })''